# `\write` non-printable ASCII characters to a file

Tags: tex-core, write

`\immediate\write\SomeStream{x}` writes `x` to the file open in `\SomeStream`. I would like to write non-printable ASCII characters, such as ``, to a file. My naive guess is

```
\begingroup         %To keep the catcode change local
\catcode`\=11
\immediate\write\SomeStream{}
\endgroup
```

But this writes the three characters `^^A` instead of the single character ``. Is there a way to prevent TeX from sanitizing its output?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newwrite\SomeStream
\immediate\openout\SomeStream NonPrintableASCII.test

\begingroup         %To keep the catcode change local
\catcode`\=11
\immediate\write\SomeStream{}
\endgroup

\immediate\closeout\SomeStream
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: My goal was to write a file and reread it with potentially crazy catcode changes (And I am using non-printable characters rather than `^^A` to be more robust.). `\scantokens` does the job (see below).

Comment: Take a look at the answers in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/58aa08c7bacf6e4d/c8ec869fbed52c61) on c.t.t.

Comment: @TH.: I did, and they confirm what Leo is saying: the user has to add a flag when compiling.

Comment: I don't think so. I think you can specify it on the first line. `%& -translate-file=natural.tcx`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some of the TeX engines, no way.
It depends on the TeX engine you use. Some of them can use a translate file (`foo.tcx`) to do this. For example, pdfTeX:

```
pdflatex -translate-file=natural.tcx foo.tex
```

Comment: thank you, I have found a different solution to my particular problem, but your answer is good!

Comment: This works great with `\write\outputfile{^^A}` etc., but is it possible to avoid the line break added by the `\write`?

Comment: @Martin: In TeX every `\write` writes a text line to the file. It automatically adds a 0x0A at end of a line. It seems that TeX cannot write a binary file. Even input is only possible with pdfTeX's `\pdffiledump`. Maybe you can store the bytes into a macro and write them at one time, but it's not convenient. For binary files, LuaTeX or `\write18` may help when necessary.

Comment: @LeoLiu: this does not work for the byte 127 (`^^?`), which is missing from `natural.tcx`. A better solution, pointed out to me by Hans Hagen, is to use the flag `-8bit` in `pdftex`.

Answer (score 4):

I know that the following solves the task with every available tex engine with the following pattern:

```
\begingroup
\count0=0
\countdef\counter=0
\catcode`\^^00=11   \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfp@bin@\the\counter \endcsname{^^00}\advance\counter by1
catcode`\^^01=11    \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfp@bin@\the\counter \endcsname{^^01}\advance\counter by1
\catcode`\^^02=11   \expandafter\xdef\csname pgfp@bin@\the\counter \endcsname{^^02}\advance\counter by1
\endgroup
```

then use `\csname pgfp@bin@0\endcsname` to get the binary char 0, `\csname pgfp@bin@1\endcsname` for the binary char 1 and so on. It becomes a real mess with those characters which have a meaning in TeX, though (but I don't see another way around that problem).
But I am sure you can adapt it to your application.

The code above is actually an extract of pgfplotsbinary.code.tex -- the pgfplots package uses it to generate low level shadings. If needed, you can copy-paste the special handling for TeX characters from that file.

It also has a "public" interface which is ready to use. I copy-paste its API here:

```
% Returns a single character, which has the
% binary ASCII code '#1', with catcode 11.
%
% #1 (expands to) a number between 0 and 255 (inclusive).
%
% @see \pgfplotsgetchar Note that \pgfplotsgetchar is more powerful,
% but can't be used inside of \edef (it is not expandable) whereas
% \pgfplotscharno is.
\def\pgfplotscharno#1{\csname pgfp@bin@#1\endcsname}%

% Defines \pgfplotsretval to be the ASCII character for #1, with
% catcode 11.
%
% #1: either a number between 0 and 255 (inclusive) or a description
% of the character.
%
% Examples:
% \pgfplotsgetchar{35}
% \pgfplotsgetchar{`\#}   % code for '#'
% \pgfplotsgetchar{`\^^M} % Newline
% \pgfplotsgetchar{`\^^ff}% 255
%
% @see \pgfplotscharno
\def\pgfplotsgetchar#1{...}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this works fine within a single TeX run, but try writing to a file with `\newwrite\mywrite\immediate\openout\mywrite\immediate\write\mywrite{\csname pgf@bin@1\endcsname}\immediate\closeout\mywrite`, and you will see that it produces 3 bytes.

Comment: OK... perhaps I misunderstood the problem then. The code above worked fine when I wrote the output directly into a pdf stream (for example with `\immediate\pdfobj stream`in the pdftex driver).
I have just tried

`\pgfplotsgetchar{1}
Here is it: `\pgfplotsretval'
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite=P.dat
\immediate\write\mywrite{\pgfplotsretval}
\immediate\closeout\mywrite`

and it resulted it ``9.746 529.281 Td [(Here)-333(is)-334(it:)-333(`\001')]TJ`` in the pdf text part... but as you said, the `\write` generated escape chars.

Comment: This works in combination with Leo Liu's answer. It actually solves the issue of handling the otherwise forbidden or otherwise used "characters". However, I don't understand why `\xdef` and not simple `\gdef` is used.

Comment: @Martin thinking about it, I do not understand it either. Perhaps I was unsure about it when I wrote the code and did never revise it because it worked as expected... apparently, `\gdef` will do the job as well (perhaps slightly more efficient).

Comment: Note that I finally had to realize that my approach does not work at all for lualatex: it does not accept binary content this way (only via LUA macros).

Answer (score 3):

I asked for a way to write non-printable characters to a file, and Leo Liu's answer gives a way to do that `:)`.

Since my goal was in fact to reread the file in TeX, protecting it against changes in the catcode of `^`, there is another way. The eTeX primitive `\scantokens` rereads its argument (this is almost equivalent to writing to a file and rereading with possibly different catcodes).

To show how it works, we first make `^^A` active, and define it to something.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\^^A=13
\def^^A{text}
```

Then we use it in a definition, and check that `\scantokens` does what it should: the line expands to `Some text`.

```
\def\foo{Some ^^A}
\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\foo}
```

Finally, we change the catcode of `^` to invalid (`15`), and repeat the process. The same `Some text` is typeset.

```
\catcode`\^=15\relax
\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\foo}
\end{document}
```

The fact that TeX does not complain about the characters `^^` is that they have in fact disappeared: `^^A` was changed to one character when defining `\foo`.