# File copy without expansion

Tags: tex-core, external-files, auxiliary-files, filesystem-access

What is the command for file copy? I want to copy the contents of one file into another without any command expansion. In a command line driven operating system one  would use

```
copy source target
```

I tried reading the contents of one file into a variable and the writing it into the target:

```
\CatchFileDef{\OriginalF}{\jobname.sc0}{}
\newwrite\hcOutputStreamF
\immediate\openout\hcOutputStreamF=\jobname.sc1
\immediate\write\hcOutputStreamF{\OriginalF}
\immediate\closeout\hcOutputStreamF
```

but it expands the TeX commands saved in the original file.

Comment: While Hector knows it, for others I wanted to note that `\CatchFileDef` is from the http://ctan.org/pkg/catchfile package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a Plain TeX solution that uses the *ε*-TeX extension `\readline`. It copies its source to `\jobname.copy`.

```
\newread\in
\openin\in=\jobname.tex
\newwrite\out
\immediate\openout\out\jobname.copy
\endlinechar-1
\loop \unless\ifeof\in
        \readline\in to\l
        \immediate\write\out{\l}
\repeat
\immediate\closeout\out
\closein\in
\end
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`verbatimcopy`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/verbatimcopy) package provides the command `\VerbatimCopy` which seems to do exactly what you are looking for. It doesn't seem to work for "binary" (i.e., non-text) files, though.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{verbatimcopy}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \VerbatimCopy{input.tex}{input.tmp}
  \input{input.tmp}

  % This doesn't work for binary files:
  %\VerbatimCopy{img.png}{img2.png}
  %\includegraphics{img2.png}
\end{document}
```

I have added a [compilable example](https://github.com/muelleki/lm-template/tree/verbatimcopy) to GitHub.

Answer (score 6):

You were very close in your original question; just replace

```
\immediate\write\hcOutputStreamF{\OriginalF}
```

with

```
\immediate\write\hcOutputStreamF{\unexpanded\expandafter{\OriginalF}}
```

and I think you'll get what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

This one comes fairly close. The trick is to make every character non-special while copying.

```
\def\everythingother{%
  \count255=0
  \loop\catcode\count255=12
    \advance\count255 1
    \ifnum\count255<256 \repeat}

\newread\infile
\newwrite\outfile
\newif\ifgo

\begingroup
\obeylines
\gdef\copyfileverbatim#1#2{%
 \begingroup\everythingother
 \obeylines
 \def^^M{}
 \immediate\openin\infile=#1
  \immediate\openout\outfile=#2
  \loop
    \read\infile to\data
    \immediate\write\outfile{\data}%
    \ifeof\infile\infile\gofalse\else\gotrue\fi
    \ifgo\repeat
  \closein\infile
  \immediate\closeout\outfile
  \endgroup}
\endgroup

\copyfileverbatim{tt.in}{tt.out}
\bye
```

One remaining problem: any control character in the input will be copied to its TeX equivalent, so a backspace character becomes `^^H`. I have no fix for that.

Comment: But honestly, I find the stated requirement somewhat bizarre. Why use TeX to copy files when every operating system does it better?

Comment: File A was created at the beginning of the process and contains some TeX code. File A is copied to file B at the end of the TeX compilation. In the second run, I use file B to generate a "table of contents". If the compilation halted, then file B was not copied and the "table of contents" is not generated (this is what I want). If I use only one file in this work flow, then there is no way (that I know of) to prevent an incomplete file A to produce the incorrect input for the second run.

Comment: you might be interested in the answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/write-non-printable-ascii-characters-to-a-file

Comment: @Hector: How about using a `\newif\ifsuccess`, and then at the end (where you would otherwise do 'copy fileA fileB') put `\addtocontents{aux}{\successtrue}`. You can then use `\ifsuccess\input{file}\else No ToC\fi` (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

A solution in expl3, for future reference. The reading part is pretty much identical to [How can I read the whole file content verbatim into a (expl3) string variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647304/250119).

```
%! TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{source.txt}
line 1  !?#\xyz
line 2
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior {source.txt}
\iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {target.txt}
\ior_str_map_variable:NNn \g_tmpa_ior \l_tmpa_str {
    \iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {\l_tmpa_str}
}
\ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
\iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

You can see the block between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` will copy the file named `source.txt` to `target.txt`.

Note for all of the existing answers (including this one), since they use TeX primitives to read the data, trailing spaces (and possibly tabs, depends on the version) on each line will be stripped, and if the source file has no final newline it will be added. (thus binary files cannot be copied.)

---

An alternative includes using shell-escape. Refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585404/250119.

Comment: You could also allocate your own file streams for "code readability" -- unlike the old `\newread`/`\newwrite`, expl3 commands implement a "reference counting" system for the files to reduce the number of files used.