# Expanding #1 for use in addtostream

Tags: input

I'm attempting to use the `newfile` package and `\input` to automate some document generation, specifically to generate a test specification's result log from a list of actions and each action's expected results. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{output}
\openoutputfile{generated.output}{output}

\newcommand{\problematic}[1]{
 \expandafter\item Original: #1
 % This is the problem:
 \addtostream{output}{\arabic{enumi} \alph{enumii}) #1 \\}
 % Clue? This results in @par in the output, rather than paragraph break
 %\addtostream{output}{\arabic{enumi} \alph{enumii}) #1\par}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Original list}
\begin{enumerate}
\item An action.
 \begin{enumerate}
   \problematic{Simple result is fine.}
   \problematic{This one is troublesome, because:
     % Uncomment to break:
     %\begin{enumerate}
     %   \item I'm having trouble
     %   \item writing this list.
     %\end{enumerate}
    }
   \problematic{This result is also fine, but how to I correctly expand \#1 in addtostream?}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\closeoutputstream{output}

\section{Included content}
\input{generated.output}

\end{document}
```

`\problematic` should output an `\item` and write #1 to a stream for `\input` later. `\expandafter` works for the `\item`, but I'm having issues with the `\addtostream`. I've tried using `\expandafter` in various combinations to no avail. As the MWE stands, when the lines below `% Uncomment to break` are uncommented, compilation fails with:

```
! Argument of \@mklab has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.28     }
```

Ultimately the `\problematic` macro will write lines in a form suitable for input into a longtable. What is the magical incantation required to get the 1st argument of `\problematic` to be written to the output stream?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! `\expandafter\item Original` expands the `O` before `\item` which in consequence does nothing as `O` is not expandable.

Comment: You don't want to expand `#1` but rather the opposite: `\addtostream{output}{\arabic{enumi} \alph{enumii}) \unexpanded{#1}}` (I also think that you don't want or need ``\\`` at the end.)

Comment: It seems like you want to reconstruct a list so IMHO it would be better to actually rebuild a real list (including `\item`'s etc)

Comment: Something like `\addtostream{output}{\noexpand\item[\arabic{enumi}\alph{enumii})] \unexpanded{#1}}` and `\begin{itemize}
\input{generated.output}
\end{itemize}`

Comment: Excellent! `\unexpanded{#1}` was the magic I was after (and works in the Fully Broken Example!)  If you create an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: For the googlers searching for "how to write a newline using newfile": `^^J` writes a newline to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @clemens points out what I needed was not to expand `#1`, but the very opposite, in `\unexpanded`, as described in this question: [How to write a command to file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/how-to-write-a-command-to-file) (albeit without `newfile`).