# listing's lst@BeginWrite gobbles '->' and '=>' from input

Tags: listings, verbatim, write-file

I'm trying to write a package that takes verbatim input and appends it to several files. My current approach is based of off an [answer by Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37795/6128) to a similar problem. The difficulty arises in that all occurrences of `=>` and `->` in the input are not output to `\jobname.xtr` nor to the desired files. That's to say, for

```
\begin{extract}[foo.bel]
a -> b
\end{extract}
```

we have `a  b` output to the files instead of `a -> b`. I believe this may be due to an occurrence of

```
\lstset{literate=%
                 {=>}{{$\Rightarrow~$}}2 %
                 {->}{{$\rightarrow~$}}2 %
}
```

in the document's prelude, since it does not occur with `\lstset{literate={}}`. Short of unsetting the `literate` option for `lstset`, how does one fix this?

The whole package is included below, since it only consists of the required macros (e.g. `appendtofile`, `apendfiletofile`, etc.) for the problematic `extract` environment at the bottom.

```
%% This is file 'extract.sty'
%%
%% Copyright (C) 2012 Ryan Kavanagh <rak@debian.org>
%%
%% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2003/12/01 or later.
%%
%% This work has the LPPL maintenance status ``author-maintained''.
%%
%% \appendfile is by Martin Scharrer and was obtained from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12414/6128
%% It too is distributed under the LLPL 1.3c or later.
%
% Usage:
%
% \begin{extract}[a,b,c,d]
%   Some verbatim text to be displayed using whichever lstlisting configurations
%   are active. This text will be appended to the files a, b, c, and d.
%
%   To set the listings options precede `\begin{extract}[files]' with a
%   '\lstset{listings options here}'.
% \end{extract}
%
% \begin{extract*}
%   Some text to be appended to the files a, b, c, and d, but not displayed.
% \end{extract*}
%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{extract}[2012/05/29 v0.1 extracts lstlistings to files]

\RequirePackage{catchfile}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{pstricks}

\def\recordfile#1{appendtofile@seen@#1}
\def\srecordfile#1{\expandafter\csname appendtofile@seen@#1\endcsname}
\def\defrecordfile#1{%
  \expandafter\def\csname appendtofile@seen@#1\endcsname{defined}
}

\newwrite\appendwrite
\newcommand*\appendtofile[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \PackageWarning{extract}{\recordfile{#1}}
  % ifundefined takes command name *without the slash*
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\srecordfile{#1}}{defined}}{%
    % Keep existing EOL
    \CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{\endlinechar=`^^J\catcode\endlinechar=12\obeyspaces\relax}
  }{%
    % If we've not yet output to this file from this run, empty it
    % Prevents having files with multiple concatenations of the same thing, one
    % for each LaTeX run.
    \global\defrecordfile{#1}
    \let\filecontent\empty
  }
  \immediate\openout\appendwrite=#1\relax
  \immediate\write\appendwrite{\filecontent #2}%
  \immediate\closeout\appendwrite
  \endgroup
}

\newread\appendingfile
\newcommand*\appendfiletofile[2]{%
  \begingroup
  % ifundefined takes command name *without the slash*
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\srecordfile{#1}}{defined}}{%
    % Keep existing EOL
    \CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{\endlinechar=`^^J\catcode\endlinechar=12\obeyspaces\relax}
  }{%
    %\expandafter\ifcsundef{recordfile{#1}}{%
    % If we've not yet output to this file from this run, empty it
    % Prevents having files with multiple concatenations of the same thing, one
    % for each LaTeX run.
    \global\defrecordfile{#1}
    \let\filecontent\empty
  }
  \openin\appendingfile=#2
  \immediate\openout\appendwrite=#1\relax
  \endlinechar-1
  \immediate\write\appendwrite{\filecontent }
  \loop \unless\ifeof\appendingfile
      \readline\appendingfile to\line
      \immediate\write\appendwrite{\line}
  \repeat
  \immediate\closeout\appendwrite
  \immediate\closein\appendingfile
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand\firstunempty[3]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{% Do nothing if empty
 }{
  #1#2#3
 }
}

\newcommand\appendtofilewrapper[2]{\firstunempty{\appendtofile}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\appendfiletofilewrapper[2]{\firstunempty{\appendfiletofile}{#1}{#2}}

\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\lstnewenvironment{extract}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
    \PackageError{extract}{extract with no filenames passed!}
  }{}
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\jobname.xtr}%
}{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile
  \psforeach{\F}{#1,}{\appendfiletofilewrapper{\F}{{\jobname.xtr}}}
  \lstinputlisting{\jobname.xtr}
}

\lstnewenvironment{extract*}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
    \PackageError{extract}{extract* with no filenames passed!}
  }{}
  \lst@BeginWriteFile{\jobname.xtr}%
}{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile
  \psforeach{\F}{#1,}{\appendfiletofilewrapper{\F}{{\jobname.xtr}}}
}

\makeatother
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example instead of a whole package.

Comment: I added a mini-example. As stated above, the whole package was provided because it only consists of the required macros for the extract environment.

Comment: Sorry but this isn't a MWE. Please read: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to understand what you're doing in that package (note that there already is an `extract` package).

However, removing the global `\lstset` setting and saying

```
\lstinputlisting[literate={=>}{{$\Rightarrow~$}}2%
  {->}{{$\rightarrow~$}}2]{\jobname.xtr}
```

instead of

```
\lstinputlisting{\jobname.xtr}
```

cures the problem. Probably you can start from here.

Are you *really* loading `pstricks` just for `\psforeach`?