# `\unexpand\expandafter` add spaces : how to append a text at the end of a file

Tags: expansion, write, write-file

I'd like to append code to a file containing latex code... So I tried the solution proposed here, but unfortunately it fails when there are backslash in the file: [How can I open a file in "append" mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-append-mode)

So I tried to adapt it with `\unexpand\expandafter{\filecontent}#2`, but it adds spaces after "commands", which is really annoying:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{catchfile}

\newwrite\appendwrite
\newcommand*\appendtofile[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \IfFileExists{#1}%
      {\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{\endlinechar=`^^J\catcode\endlinechar=12\relax}}% keep existing end-of-lines
      {\let\filecontent\empty}%
    \immediate\openout\appendwrite=#1\relax
    \immediate\write\appendwrite{\unexpanded\expandafter{\filecontent}#2}%
    \immediate\closeout\appendwrite
    \endgroup
}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname.test}{\string\Mycode\themycounter}

First, everything is good:\\
\verbatiminput{\jobname.test}

\appendtofile{\jobname.test}{Second line}

Second, see how the spaces are added:\\
\verbatiminput{\jobname.test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The behaviour is by-design: you'll have to go for a token-by-token conversion to a string to avoid it

Comment: @JosephWright I have no idea how to do that (LaTeX is still a mystery for me), could you provide an example please?

Comment: This happens because when TeX reads the file the ``\`` is the control character thus `\Mycode` is a control sequence and TeX adds a space after that, as Joseph said, by-design. You can do `\let\do\@makeother\dospecials` before `\CatchFileDef` then the file would be read verbatim and `\Mycode0` would be just a sequence of 8 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the file back with a verbatim `\`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{catchfile}

\newwrite\appendwrite
\newcommand*\appendtofile[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \IfFileExists{#1}%
      {\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{\catcode`\\=12 \endlinechar=`^^J\catcode\endlinechar=12\relax}}% keep existing end-of-lines
      {\let\filecontent\empty}%
    \immediate\openout\appendwrite=#1\relax
    \immediate\write\appendwrite{\detokenize\expandafter{\filecontent}#2}%
    \immediate\closeout\appendwrite
    \endgroup
}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname.test}{\string\Mycode\themycounter}

First, everything is good:\\
\verbatiminput{\jobname.test}

\appendtofile{\jobname.test}{Second line}

Second, see how the spaces are added:\\
\verbatiminput{\jobname.test}

\end{document}
```