# How to write and expand \gls command to a text file?

Tags: glossaries, expansion, glossaries-extra, write

Is it possible to expand the `\gls` command in order to print it's "output" in a text file?

Here a 'MWE.tex' file content:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{myglsentry}{name={Myglsentry},description={myglsentry desc}}

\newwrite\mytextfile
\immediate\openout\mytextfile=\jobname.txt

\begin{document}
\glsaddall

\immediate\write\mytextfile{\glsname{myglsentry}}

\immediate\closeout\mytextfile

\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

This MWE gives this result in 'MWE.txt':
[image]

How can I obtain this result instead (i.e. the "output" of the `\glsname{myglsentry}` command call):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to expand the argument of `\write` once with `\unexpanded\expandafter` (see for example [Partially expanding a command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116823/partially-expanding-a-command) and [`\unexpand\expandafter` add spaces : how to append a text at the end of a file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484380/unexpand-expandafter-add-spaces-how-to-append-a-text-at-the-end-of-a-file)) and use the most low-level macro from `glossaries`, that contains the contents with a single expansion.

The macro containing the contents is `\glo@some_entry@name`, in this case `\glo@myglsentry@name`. Because this macro contains the `@` symbol you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{myglsentry}{name={Myglsentry},description={myglsentry desc}}

\newwrite\mytextfile
\immediate\openout\mytextfile=\jobname.txt

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\makeatletter
\immediate\write\mytextfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\glo@myglsentry@name}}
\makeatother

\immediate\closeout\mytextfile

\printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it would be more easy to use... Indeed I need this for automaticly write gls entries "output" to a file. I tried to create a command like `\renewcommand*{\glsname}[1]{\makeatletter\glo@#1@name\makeatother}` but the use of `\unexpanded` make the `#1` unexpanded ;) Do you think I shoud ask a new question for this?

Comment: @SylvainRigal it's not the `\unexpanded` that's the problem there, it's the way of creating a macro name out of different pieces. The `@` is nothing special, it's just a letter (because `\makeatletter` was used, i.e., make 'at' a letter). So it is similar to create for example `\mycommandname` out of `\my` and `command` and `name`. This is possible in LaTeX but you need the `\csname` construct for this (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39380/what-exactly-do-csname-and-endcsname-do for example).

Comment: Also, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` need to be _outside_ of the macro definition, they need to take effect when the macro is created, not when it is executed. However, with such a setup you would need _two_ expansions, one to expand the (renewed) `\glsname` and one to expand `\glo@xyz@name` while `\unexpanded\expandafter` only performs _one_ expansion - this is the whole reason to use the most low-level macro in the first place instead of a higher-level macro that calls a series of increasingly lower level macros.

Comment: But I'm not sure why you can't just use `\write\mytextfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\glo@myglsentry@name}}` and you want to use `\write\mytextfile{\glsname{myglsentry}}` instead?

Comment: And about your last comment, it's hard to explain here but I need to write a "list" of gls entries outputs automatically, so I need to be able to automatically change the `xyz` in `\glo@xyz@name`. AND my gls entries could be defined with another entries like for e.g. the `name` field could be defined as: `name={\glsname{anotherglsentrie} Myglsentry},`. This is why I want to redefine the `\glsname` command (just for the purpose of writting to a file)...

Comment: I sincerely thank you for your comments. I define this `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\glsname}[1]{\csname glo@#1@name\endcsname}\makeatother` and when I do this (without any unexpansion) `\immediate\write\mytextfile{\glsname{myglsentry}}` it well write the "output" of `\glsname` (i.e. `Myglsentry`) to the file !!! Do you know why it works without unexpansion?

Comment: I wonder what are the low level macros names corresponding to all the `\gls` like commands (I posted a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634559/262081) for that).