# How to achieve cross-referencing in glossary entries properly?

Tags: cross-referencing, glossaries, best-practices, glossaries-extra

Usually, I define some glossary entries fields (as `name`, `text`, `symbol` fields) by another glossary entry like below (the `compressor_motor` entry is define with the `compressor` entry):

```
\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \glsname{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}
```

I do that because I have a lot of entries depending to another entries and I don't want to change a lot of things if I just decide to change the word "compressor" by "compresseur" (in french for exemple). One of the reasons why I use LaTeX is precisely because I don't have to do this type of modification manually...

However, this way of "cross-defining" entries makes unsable the capitilized `\gls` like commands (as `\Gls`, `\GLS`, etc.) (I already ask a question for that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/632825/262081)).

This problem made me wonder if my way of defining the entries was correct or acceptable with regard to the way the `glossaries` package is designed...

**So, is my way of "cross-referencing" between glossary entries correct?**

**If not, then what is the correct way to do it, should I use another format to declare the entries (e.g. `.bib` and `bib2gls` engine) or something else?**

> In order to avoid misunderstandings, **the capitalization problem is already addressed in the question cited above, I don't want to create a duplicate here**. My question here is about "correct practice" or at least a better practice regarding defining glossary entries if one wants certain entries to be dependent on other glossary entries. I don't want a opinion based answer but **I would simply like to know if I am missing a technique that would be unknown to me but obvious to others...**

Here a MWE if needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=tree]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{subsytem}{name={Subssytems},description={\glspar},sort={1}}   
\newglossaryentry{compressor}
{
    name={Compressor},
    text={compressor},
    sort={compressor},
    description={Air Compressor},
    symbol={cp},
    parent=subsytem
}
\newglossaryentry{ejector}
{
    name={Ejector},
    text={ejector},
    sort={Ejector},
    description={Air Ejector},
    symbol={ej},
    parent=subsytem
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_motor}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor} Motor},
    sort={compressor motor},
    text={\gls{compressor} motor},
    description={Motor of the \glsname{compressor}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}m},
    parent=compressor
}

\newglossaryentry{compressor_ejector}
{
    name={\glsname{compressor}~and \glsname{ejector}},
    sort={compressor and ejector},
    text={\gls{compressor}~and \gls{ejector}},
    description={Air \glsname{compressor} and \glsname{ejector}},
    symbol={\glssymbol{compressor}\glssymbol{ejector}},
    parent=subsytem
}


\begin{document}

    \gls{compressor};
    \gls{compressor_motor};
    \gls{compressor_ejector};
    
    \bigskip

    \printnoidxglossary
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at chapter 11 of the `glossaries` manual (and the resources referenced there)?

Comment: @schtandard If I well understand the manual, the answer to my question is yes: my way of "cross-referencing" between glossary entries is correct, there is no more appropriate way of doing. Thank you very much for your comment, I discovered the `see` key which I will try a little I think.

Comment: @schtandard Since this question has no real answer other than your comment, you could turn your comment into an answer if you want.