# Inconsistent behaviour of \detokenize on macro beginning with "e" or "f"

Tags: shell-escape, write, bash

I need to write to a file the unexpanded LaTeX. The macro `\OuputToFile` is bascially an `\immediate\write18` and works fine with the following:

```
\OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\cXXX{X}}$}}%
\OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\dXXX{X}}$}}%
```

where the inner macros begin with `c` and `d`. BUT, has problems if they being with `e` or `f`. That is, the following does not yield the desired results:

```
\OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\eXXX{X}}$}}%
\OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\fXXX{X}}$}}%
```

Why is this, but more importantly how do I remedy this situation?

The output of the MWE below is

[image]

but the desired result is

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\immediate\write18{printf "\\n" > foo.tex }% Initialize File

\NewDocumentCommand{\OuputToFile}{%
    m% string to output
}{%
    \immediate\write18{printf 'string = "#1"' >> foo.tex }%
    \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" >> foo.tex }%
}

\def\MyString{$\OuterMacro{\InnerMacro{X}}$}


\begin{document}
    Output to file: 
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\cXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\dXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\eXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\fXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\gXXX{X}}$}}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: nothing to do with tex,  try `printf "\cXXX"` on the commandline and compare with `printf "\eXXX"`  why use printf rather than just writing the file directly?

Comment: you could use `printf "%s" "\eXXX"` etc which prints `\eXXX`  or use echo instead of printf

Comment: Every `\OuputToFile` instruction generates a write to the log file of the form `runsystem(printf 'string = "$\OuterMacro {\cXXX {X}}$"' >> foo.tex )...disabled (restricted).` Do I need to enable something?

Comment: @Mico: I think you need `-shell-escape`.

Comment: (there's also [tex core - How can I open a file in "append" mode? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-append-mode), as well as solutions that handle everything in memory)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is nothing to do with TeX, `\e` is a control character to `printf`.

If you try

```
printf "\cXXX"
```

on the command line you get  `\cXXX`

But if you try

```
printf "\eXXX"
```

you get nothing.

You could use

```
echo -n "\eXXX"
```

or

```
printf "%s" "\eXXX"
```

both of which yield `\eXXX`, so ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\immediate\write18{printf "\\n" > foo.tex }% Initialize File

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\OuputToFile}{%
    m% string to output
}{%
    \immediate\write18{printf '\@percentchar s' 'string = "#1"' >> foo.tex }%
    \immediate\write18{printf "\\n" >> foo.tex }%
}
\makeatother

\def\MyString{$\OuterMacro{\InnerMacro{X}}$}


\begin{document}
    Output to file: 
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\cXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\dXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\eXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\fXXX{X}}$}}%
    \OuputToFile{\detokenize{$\OuterMacro{\gXXX{X}}$}}%
\end{document}
```

produces a `foo.tex`

```
string = "$\OuterMacro {\cXXX {X}}$"
string = "$\OuterMacro {\dXXX {X}}$"
string = "$\OuterMacro {\eXXX {X}}$"
string = "$\OuterMacro {\fXXX {X}}$"
string = "$\OuterMacro {\gXXX {X}}$"
```