Dynamically growing an enumerated list in a file
Please consider the MWE below. This is a simplified version of a large project.
I need to create an enumerated list that is generated dynamically during runtime. This list is included at some later point in the file.
I tried using the technique from this answer.
\documentclass{article}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12414/14103
\usepackage{catchfile}
\newwrite\appendwrite
\newcommand*\appendtofile[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \IfFileExists{#1}%
      {\CatchFileDef{\filecontent}{#1}{\endlinechar=`^^J\catcode\endlinechar=12\relax}}% keep existing end-of-lines
      {\let\filecontent\empty}%
    \immediate\openout\appendwrite=#1\relax
    \immediate\write\appendwrite{\filecontent #2}%
    \immediate\closeout\appendwrite
    \endgroup
}

% Create the seed file
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname_list}
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname_list}{\item More text 3}

\begin{enumerate}
\input {\jobname_list}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

However, when executed, I am getting the following error message.

! Use of \@item doesn't match its definition.
\@ifnextchar ...eserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}
                                                  \def \reserved@b {#3}\futu...
l.24 ...ndtofile{\jobname_list}{\item More text 3}



if the whole file is generated within the run it would be much simpler and more efficient  just to \write to it each time, not \close the stream and then have to append by re-opening and copying the whole file each time you add a line

@DavidCarlisle, I will have around fifty files created at the same time. I am facing the upper limit of 16 streams which can be kept open simultaneously. As such, I can not keep them all open.

luatex has 128 streams not 16 so if you can use luatex that isn't an issue

@DavidCarlisle Yes, life is simpler if we are using LuaTeX only. This should be main recommendation almost at every thread here.

@wipet I thought of you while writing the previous comment:-)

@wipet, Where do I begin if I want to start using LuaTeX? I have been using TeX since 1991, and LaTeX since early 2000.

@Masroor I am not LaTeX user, so I am not able to advice how to switch from LaTeX to LaTeX. If you want to switch from LaTeX to OpTeX, then I am ready to help you.

I'd not use this approach, more on this later.
You can implement it more easily with expl3 using \iow_now:Nn that does no expansion during the write operation.
% Create the seed file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname_list}
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtofile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = tokens to append
  \masroor_file_append:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\iow_new:N \g_masroor_file_iow
\tl_new:N \l__masroor_file_contents_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masroor_file_append:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  % \l__masroor_file_contents_tl is empty at this time
  \file_if_exist:nT {#1}
   {
    \file_get:nnN {#1} {\endlinechar=`^^J} \l__masroor_file_contents_tl
   }
  % append the current contents
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__masroor_file_contents_tl {#2}
  \iow_open:Nn \g_masroor_file_iow {#1}
  \iow_now:NV \g_masroor_file_iow \l__masroor_file_contents_tl
  \iow_close:N \g_masroor_file_iow
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname_list}{\item More text 3}

\begin{enumerate}
\input {\jobname_list}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

The contents of \jobname_list.tex at the end is
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\item More text 3

which is exactly what you want.
How would I do it? Assuming that at the end you want to have the final versions of the file, you can define a sequence for each one, load the previous version at the beginning and, when needed or at the end, write out them.
% Create the seed file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname_list}
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setupfile}{m}
 {
  \masroor_file_setup:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtofile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = tokens to append
  \masroor_file_append:nn {#1} {#2}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\fileuse}{O{}m}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { g_masroor_file_(#2)_seq } {#1}
 }

\ior_new:N \g_masroor_file_get_ior
\iow_new:N \g_masroor_file_iow
\seq_new:N \g_masroor_file_list_seq

\AtEndDocument
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_masroor_file_list_seq
   {
    \iow_open:Nn \g_masroor_file_iow {#1}
    \iow_now:Ne \g_masroor_file_iow { \seq_use:cn { g_masroor_file_(#1)_seq } {^^J} }
    \iow_close:N \g_masroor_file_iow
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masroor_file_setup:n
 {
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_masroor_file_(#1)_seq }
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_masroor_file_list_seq {#1}
  \file_if_exist:nT {#1}
   {
    \ior_open:Nn \g_masroor_file_get_ior {#1}
    \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_masroor_file_get_ior
     {
      \seq_gput_right:ce { g_masroor_file_(#1)_seq } { \tl_trim_spaces:n {##1} }
     }
    \ior_close:N \g_masroor_file_get_ior
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masroor_file_append:nn
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g_masroor_file_(#1)_seq } {#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setupfile{\jobname_list}

\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname_list}{\item More text 3}

\begin{enumerate}
\fileuse{\jobname_list}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

With \fileuse we simply use the sequence as it is at the time of call. At end document all files are written out.
Addition from comments
If the argument to \appendtofile has to be expanded because you want to pass macros containing runtime data, you need to protect dangerous commands and \text_expand:n is your friend, because it keeps quiet all “robust” commands. You just need to protect those that would fail in moving arguments anyway: \item is one of the few.
% Create the seed file
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname_list}
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\appendtofile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = tokens to append
  \masroor_file_append:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\iow_new:N \g_masroor_file_iow
\tl_new:N \l__masroor_file_contents_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \masroor_file_append:nn
 {
  \group_begin:
  % \l__masroor_file_contents_tl is empty at this time
  \file_if_exist:nT {#1}
   {
    \file_get:nnN {#1} {\endlinechar=`^^J} \l__masroor_file_contents_tl
   }
  % protect dangerous commands
  \text_declare_expand_equivalent:Nn \item { \exp_not:n { \item } }
  % append the current contents
  \tl_put_right:Ne \l__masroor_file_contents_tl { \text_expand:n {#2} }
  \iow_open:Nn \g_masroor_file_iow {#1}
  \iow_now:NV \g_masroor_file_iow \l__masroor_file_contents_tl
  \iow_close:N \g_masroor_file_iow
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mypieceofdata}{3}

\begin{document}

\appendtofile{\jobname_list}{\item More text \textbf{\mypieceofdata}}

\begin{enumerate}
\input {\jobname_list}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

A similar adjustment can be done for the other implementation. The final contents of the _list file is
\item Original 1
\item Original 2
\item More text \textbf {3}


Perhaps I am going to use the first version. The files generated will be used (included inside the respective enumerate environments) at some later point. I am waiting before I accept your answer to see whether a better one comes in the meantime. :-)

What if there are some values that I want expanded when being written in the file?  For example, let us say, I am appending \item text \macroone text \macrotwo to the file. I want \macroone and \macrotwo written in their expanded form. Sorry, but please call me ignorant when it comes to LaTeX3.

@Masroor That would require a more detailed description of what you expect as the argument to \appendtofile.

@Masroor I added how to do what you want.

You have to suppress expanding of \item macros during \write:
\immediate\write\appendwrite{\unexpanded\expandafter{\filecontent #2}}%

The line above shows where was the problem in your macros. But I don't understand why do you solve this task by external files. In fact, you want to set initial value at beginning of the document and to add additional values when the document is processed and use the current summation value at several points. The data can be accumulated in a macro, you needn't to use external files for this purpose:
\documentclass{article}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\mylist{% initial value:
   \item Original 1
   \item Original 2
}

\begin{document}

\addto\mylist{\item More text 3} % add next item to the data

\begin{enumerate}
\mylist  % use the accumulated data
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

