# How to copy contents of one file to another?

Tags: copy-paste, write-file

So I have a .txt-file and I need to import the data line per line. That works like it should. I need however to adapt the contents loaded into a command an write it to another .txt file that later will be used by the datatool package. Problem is that if I write this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newopen\copyfile  % open the file to write to
\openout\copyfile=copy.txt

\newread\file      % open the file to read from
\openin\file=file.txt

\loop\unless\ifeof\file
  \read\file to\fileline  % Read one line and store it into \fileline

  \fileline                   % print the content into the pdf
  \write\copyfile{\fileline}  % print the content to copy.txt
\repeat

\end{document}
```

The output file looks like this:

```
\par
\par
\par
...
```

While the pdf displays the actual content of the file. Here is an example of a text file for input.

data.txt:

```
This is the first line.
And the second one.
Here is the third.
And so on...
```

If anyone has another solution of making datatool skip the first `x` lines, or even better when reading a certain string, that will solve my problem too in a more efficient way `:)`

p.s.: I cannot adapt the .txt-files

Comment: I tried `\expand` and `\noexpand` btw

Comment: Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87014/8666

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're forgetting `\immediate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newwrite\copyfile  % open the file to write to
\immediate\openout\copyfile=copy.txt

\newread\file      % open the file to read from
\openin\file=data.txt

\begingroup\endlinechar=-1
\loop\unless\ifeof\file
  \read\file to\fileline  % Read one line and store it into \fileline
  \fileline\par                   % print the content into the pdf
  \immediate\write\copyfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\fileline}}  % print the content to copy.txt
\repeat
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I've added also a trick for avoiding a final blank in the expansion of `\fileline`. However the copy won't be exact, because TeX always add an empty line at the end of read in files.

The `\unexpanded\expandafter{\fileline}` avoids problems with expansion of commands possibly present in the data file.

It's quite difficult to understand *why* you'd want this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Will test it immediately. I need this because I need to import data using the package datatool. I have a large number of files which need to be processed.
The text file starts with a bunch of info, and all I need to import in datatool is the table beneath all that info. Thus, my workaround: create a new .txt without the info above the table to make datatool import it correctly.

Comment: Works flawlessly `:)` Thanks again!