# Build one single .tex file from a .tex file with multiple \input

Tags: compiling, input, include

**Edit:** *I think this question is sufficiently distinct from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically) because I am specifically asking for a method within TeX itself, i.e. not running some Perl script separately to do this, but instead having it happen automatically via some TeX magic whenever I compile the source.*

**Edit 2:** *To give some motivation for this question, I have always used `\embedfile{jobname.tex}` in my preamble to embed the source code into the PDF, but this doesn't work when you use `\include`s or `\input`s. There is `\usepackage{embedall}` (and then `\embedinput`), but this means that your source files are embedded individually. I assumed that, in compiling and making a PDF, TeX at some point generates a single .tex file with all the `\include`s and `\input`s expanded, and I was hoping to be able to use `\embedfile` to embed **this** single file into the PDF.*

I can't seem to find an answer to this question anywhere, so sorry if it's been asked before.

Assume I have some `main.tex` file with the preamble, etc., and all my chapters are in some `chapters` directory, and I use `\input{chapter1}` in `main.tex`. Is there then a way to 'compile' this structure into one single `.tex` file, i.e. with each `\input` actually expanded and replaced with the *contents* of `chapters/chapter1.tex`, `chapters/chapter2.tex`, etc.?

I'm sure this wouldn't be too much of a faff to do with some bash script, but I was hoping that there was some (La)TeX way of doing this — maybe some such file is produced in the compilation process?

---

`main.tex`

```
[preamble]

\input{chapters/chapter1.tex}

\input{chapters/chapter2.tex}

...
```

`chapters/chapter1.tex`

```
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem ipsum
```

`chapters/chapter2.tex`

```
\chapter{Second chapter}

Dolor sit amet
```

should become

`main_single.tex`

```
[preamble]

\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem ipsum

\chapter{Second chapter}

Dolor sit amet

...
```

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity I'd like to produce a copy of main.tex like that, basically, yes

Comment: So you don't want to use `\input` or `\include` but just copy the contents of each chapter into a new  main input file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace \input{fileX} by the content of fileX automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21838/replace-inputfilex-by-the-content-of-filex-automatically)

Comment: You need to do file operation in TeX, see [Copying one file to another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63463/87876)

Comment: @naphaneal that question is very similar, but I think it's different because I'm asking for a way to do this within the TeX document itself, using TeX, rather than running some Perl script separately

Comment: No such a file is not created by the compilation process (and btw: \include does more than simply include the code, it also issues a \clearpage), so you would have to write code which writes such a file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not sure, if it'd not actually be possible utilizing the `filecontents` environment. but I've neither time nor incentive to further investigate.

Comment: tex never generates a combined file, in fact it never usually has more than a page of the source file in memory. early pages are typeset before the source for later ages have even been read from disk, even if the file is in a single source.

Comment: I suppose you do not use `\embedfile{jobname.tex}` but you use `\embedfile{\jobname.tex}`.  (`\jobname` is a control-sequence, thus there is a backslash. ;-) ) Besides this: (La)TeX actually does not read input file-wise but does read the input from the file or from the console line by line only when it "thinks" that it needs to do so. The characters of a line of input in turn get tokenized only when (La)TeX thinks that it needs to do so. Thus within tex-input-files you can do a lot of commenting/documenting/whatsoever after the `\end{document}`- or `\stop`- or `\bye`- or `\endinput`-command.

Comment: @naphaneal Be aware that usually the horizontal-tab-character (codepoint 9 in ASCII and UTF-8) has catcode 10(space) and thus usually gets treated in the same way as spaces that occur in the tex-input. That's why some people use horizontal-tab for indenting their TeX source-code. Afaik the **filecontents**-environment does turn horizontal-tabs into spaces which may destroy such indenting.

Answer (score 2):

**E.g., when it comes to conditional inputting/including of files, I see problems with the approach of automatic building of a single file from the source-files.**

Also be aware that if with some of the contents of the pdf-file randomness created by the sources plays a rôle, embedding the sources alone might not provide all means needed for re-creating the pdf-file with exactly the same look.

The source may contain directives like:

If at the time of encountering the directive it is morning, include **goodmorning.tex**.
   If at the time of encountering the directive it is afternoon, include **goodafternoon.tex**.
   If at the time of encountering the directive it is night, include **goodnight.tex**.

Or within the source, the pgf-package may have been loaded for generating and displaying random numbers.

The source may contain directives for displaying the system-date and time that was current at the moment when compilation was started. (This will be different when compiling at another time.)

The source may contain directives for delivering a random mix of exercises from a pool of exercises.

...

Be that as it may.

**I suggest going the other direction:**

Combine your **main.tex** and your input-files "by hand" within a single source-file from which the single input-files can be regained (semi-)automatically by means of the [**docstrip** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip). (The [**docstrip** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) is part of standard LaTeX installations.)

The [**docstrip** package](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) is a means for deriving different .tex-input-files from one (set of) master-file(s):
Within the master-file(s) you can place so-called tags. These tags are used for determining the content of the derived files as the tagged portions of text from the master-files will be copied to the derived files.

E.g., within the head of the main master-file you can call docstrip and have so-called `\generate`-directives for creating those files that are to be derived from the master-files.

More info about [**docstrip**](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) can be found at CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip

If you save the following example as a file with a name both other than **main.tex** and other than **chapter1.tex** and other than **chapter2.tex** and compile it by calling
`tex ⟨file name⟩` or
`pdftex ⟨file name⟩` or
`latex ⟨file name⟩` or
`pdflatex ⟨file name⟩`
from the command-line/from the shell
**after** (via the `cd`-command or the `chdir`-command or whatever) **changing the working directory to the directory where you have saved that file**, you will be asked to create the sub-directory "chapters".
When you have done this, then three new files will be created:
The file **main.tex** is in the current directory.
The files **chapter1.tex** and **chapter2.tex** will be in the sub-directory **chapters**.

```
%<*ignore>
% Section with docstrip directives for generating different 
% .tex-input-files:
\input docstrip
% Patch docstrip's \makeOther so that it also makes horizontal
% tab-char other (code-point 9 in ASCII and UTF 8)
% when making space-char other - if you don't apply this patch,
% docstrip will kill horizontal tabs at the beginnings of lines
% and will turn horizontal-tabs within lines into spaces:
\def\makeOther#1{%
  \ifnum`\ =`#1 \catcode9=12\relax\fi
  \catcode`#1=12\relax
}%
%
\nopreamble
\nopostamble
\askforoverwritetrue
\begingroup
\obeyspaces
\message{%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
!! Attention 1:                                            !!^^J%
!! ------------                                            !!^^J%
!! Make sure to have changed the working directory to the  !!^^J%
!! directory where the file that is currently compiled is  !!^^J%
!! stored.                                                 !!^^J%
!! ------------------------------------------------------- !!^^J%
!! Attention 2:                                            !!^^J%
!! ------------                                            !!^^J%
!! Make sure you have created the sub-directory "chapters" !!^^J%
!! within the directory where the file that is currently   !!^^J%
!! compiled is stored.                                     !!^^J%
!! You need to do this by hand as TeX won't do it for you. !!^^J%
!! If that sub-directory does not yet exist, you can do it !!^^J%
!! now.                                                    !!^^J%
!!                                                         !!^^J%
!! Press <return> after creating that sub-directory/when   !!^^J%
!! that sub-directory exists.                              !!^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
}%
\endgroup
\immediate\read-1 to \mytempmacro
\generate{%
  \file{main.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{main}}%
  \file{./chapters/chapter1.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{chapter1}}%
  \file{./chapters/chapter2.tex}{\from{\jobname.tex}{chapter2}}%
}%
% Here you can probably insert \write18-calls suitable for your platform
% for calling pdflatex from console for compiling main.tex
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex main.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify main.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf main.tex}
%
\csname stop\endcsname % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)LaTeX
                       %    for generating the files.
\bye % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)TeX for generating the 
%    %    files.
%
%</ignore>
%
% In verbatim mode docstrip does not strip comments.
%
% Section containing main.tex
%
%<*main>
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\documentclass{book}
% [preamble]
\begin{document}
\input{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\input{chapters/chapter2.tex}
\end{document}
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
%</main>
%
% Section containing chapter1.tex
%
%<*chapter1>
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem ipsum
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
%</chapter1>
%
% Section containing chapter2.tex
%
%<*chapter2>
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\chapter{Second chapter}

Dolor sit amet
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
%</chapter2>
```

---

---

**If you absolutely don't like going the other direction:**

If there is no nested inputting/including, i.e., if the structure is of a simple pattern where **main.tex** contains the preamble, the document-environment and a few `\include`-directives for including the files containing the single chapters (which in turn do not contain such `\include`/`\input`-directives), probably adding a few things to your files that under normal circumstances are taken for comments by LaTeX is sufficient for turning your set of files into something that can be combined within a single file by means of a little script that calls [docstrip](https://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip).

I.e., if you have the file **main.tex**

```
%<*BeforeChapterInput>
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\documentclass{book}
% [preamble]
\begin{document}
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
%</BeforeChapterInput>
%<*ChapterInput>
\input{chapters/chapter1.tex}
\input{chapters/chapter2.tex}
%</ChapterInput>
%<*AfterChapterInput>
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\end{document}
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
%</AfterChapterInput>
```

and within the sub-directory **chapters** the file **chapter1.tex**

```
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem ipsum
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
```

and the file **chapter2.tex**

```
%<<This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
\chapter{Second chapter}

Dolor sit amet
%This weird line does put DocStrip into and out of verbatim mode.
```

, a file **combined.tex** can be created, which looks like this,

```
\documentclass{book}
% [preamble]
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

Lorem ipsum
\chapter{Second chapter}

Dolor sit amet
\end{document}
```

, by means of the following script - it must be stored in the same directory as **main.tex**  and it needs to be compiled by calling
`tex ⟨file name⟩` or
`pdftex ⟨file name⟩` or
`latex ⟨file name⟩` or
`pdflatex ⟨file name⟩`
from the command-line/from the shell **after** (via the `cd`-command or the `chdir`-command or whatever) **changing the working directory to the directory where you have saved both main.tex and that script.**

```
% Section with docstrip directives for generating different 
% .tex-input-files:
\input docstrip
% Patch docstrip's \makeOther so that it also makes horizontal
% tab-char other (code-point 9 in ASCII and UTF 8)
% when making space-char other - if you don't apply this patch,
% docstrip will kill horizontal tabs at the beginnings of lines
% and will turn horizontal-tabs within lines into spaces:
\def\makeOther#1{%
  \ifnum`\ =`#1 \catcode9=12\relax\fi
  \catcode`#1=12\relax
}%
%
\nopreamble
\nopostamble
\askforoverwritetrue
\begingroup
\obeyspaces
\message{%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
!! Attention 1:                                            !!^^J%
!! ------------                                            !!^^J%
!! Make sure to have changed the working directory to the  !!^^J%
!! directory where the file that is currently compiled is  !!^^J%
!! stored.                                                 !!^^J%
!! ------------------------------------------------------- !!^^J%
!! Attention 2:                                            !!^^J%
!! ------------                                            !!^^J%
!! Make sure the file main.tex is in the same directory as !!^^J%
!! the file that is currently compiled.                    !!^^J%
!! Also make sure that that directory has a subdirectory   !!^^J%
!! "chapters" where the files "chapter1.tex" and           !!^^J%
!! "chapter2.tex" can be found.                            !!^^J%
!!                                                         !!^^J%
!! Press <return> to continue.                             !!^^J%
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!^^J%
}%
\endgroup
\immediate\read-1 to \mytempmacro
\generate{%
  \file{combined.tex}{%
    \from{main.tex}{BeforeChapterInput}%
    \from{./chapters/chapter1.tex}{}%
    \from{./chapters/chapter2.tex}{}%
    \from{main.tex}{AfterChapterInput}%
  }%
}%
% Here you can probably insert \write18-calls suitable for your platform
% for calling pdflatex from console for compiling combined.tex
%
%    \immediate\write18{pdflatex combined.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{pdftexify combined.tex}
%    \immediate\write18{latexmk -pdf combined.tex}
%
\csname stop\endcsname % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)LaTeX
                       %    for generating the files.
\bye % <- end this TeX-run in case you used (pdf)TeX for generating the 
%    %    files.
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that `latexpand` worked for me, replacing all my `\input` and `\include` commands with the referenced file contents.

`latexpand` CTAN Package: https://ctan.org/pkg/latexpand

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.