# Preprocess a .tex file and save it as a new file

Tags: macros, input, include

I have several `.tex` files that I would like to share with other people. I've included in them (with the command `\input`) several files with macros that I've written myself. However, I would like to send only a self-contained `.tex` file.

What I need to do is generating another `.tex` file where the `\input` command is replaced with the content of the file, pretty much like you would do by calling just the preprocessor in C.

I guess this could be done (relatively) easily with a bit of scripting, but  I would like to know if there were a builtin option in a LaTeX compiler.

Comment: no (there are existing answers on site about this) latex never holds the source in memory or constructs the combined file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so you're saying that I have to do it by myself?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474203/build-one-single-tex-file-from-a-tex-file-with-multiple-input?r=SearchResults&s=1|42.4971  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25713/how-do-i-combine-several-tex-files-into-one/25747?r=SearchResults&s=6|20.5910#25747 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184152/make-a-standalone-version-of-multiple-files-all-document-in-one-tex-file/184585?r=SearchResults&s=8|15.0726#184585  etc

Comment: I'm saying latex won't do it, but there are lots of tools that do (or claim to do) this for you. (it is trivial to write a few lines of perl to do this on any normal document, writing a general tool that gets it right on any document and copes with the string `\input` in verbatim or comments etc is trickier but usually not needed)