# Can Latex copy external files around the computer's file system

Tags: external-files, copy-paste

I have a latex document like the below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\plott}[1]{
\begin{figure}
        \includegraphics{#1}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\plott{"c:\\documents\\chart1.pdf"}
\plott{"c:\\downloads\\chart2.pdf"}
\end{document}
```

Now as well as chart1.pdf and chart2.pdf I have files chart1.csv and chart2.csv (which live in the same folders as these charts) which contains the data that went into make the chart.

I want to add logic to \plott to copy these csvs to a third folder so that when I compile the document I get not only a document but also a folder containing all of the input data. Is it possible for latex to copy external files like this?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it feasible? No. Better add this to your build process than letting LaTeX do it.

Comment: I was hoping latex could do it as with xstring and IfFileExists it has most of what is needed - I just need to be able to copy files. If possible I don't want to use a batch file or something as that is additional dependencies, need to grep to see what charts are included, etc.

Comment: Let your macro write the file names used to another temporary file which is used by your batch file to copy the correct csvs.

Comment: There's also [tex core - File copy without expansion - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/file-copy-without-expansion?noredirect=1&lq=1) but for text files only and trailing newlines may be added/trailing spaces may be stripped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\immediate\write18` you can run an external program from a .tex file, so

```
\newcommand{\plott}[2][]{
  \immediate\write18{cp #2 plott}
   \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
   \end{figure}
}
```

(1) will include #2 in the output and

(2) will copy it into the `plott` folder.

#### Requirements for this solution:

(1) You are using a Unix-like OS.

(2) A TeX Live distribution is installed on your system.

(3) A folder named `plott` exists in the same directory of the main `.tex` file. You can create it automatically with `\immediate\write18{mkdir plott}` if you prefer.

#### A minimal working example

I used two images from TeX Live, but you can change the path, of course, and use other files:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\plott}[2][]{
\immediate\write18{cp #2 plott}
 \begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[#1]{#2}
 \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
 \plott{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-a.jpg}
 \plott{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image-b.jpg}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not using Unix but I ended up doing something similar

Comment: write18 doesn't work in LuaTeX however. There's `shellesc` package and expl3's `sys_shell_now` command.