# How to automatically assemble only required parts of class and packages into one single compilable tex file?

Tags: packages, compiling

In my daily work, I'm using several custom classes and packages. When I want to share a `tex` file, I don't want people to have to install all these custom files. Not that I don't want to share them, but it's painful for them to install.

Is there a way to create a single `tex` file, containing the `tex` content + all (and ideally only) the necessary lines from the `cls` and `sty` files I'm using? So there are only calls to standard classes (like `article`) or package?

I wasn't able to find anything on the subject but may have searched for the wrong terms.

Kind regards,

Ivan

Comment: If it is custom, then you already have the source code and it is simply a matter of cut-and-pasting the code together in one file.  What you might look at is using options to select which code get used (not everything that appears in the code is expanded).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't find it that 'simple' to copy/paste everything that is needed, especially if it has to be done on a regular basis (but to send to different people). I tought that maybe (xe)latex would know, at some point in the process, what it is using from my files and what it isn't. Thus being able to direct all this in an `tex` file as output, just like a browser knows what to display even in the case of several stylesheets (but xelatex is not a browser, I agree).

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific? Do you know an editor that can do that? I'm using TeXstudio for now and don't know about such option.

Comment: Thank you. I can't use it, it's only running on Windows and I'm on Debian. I don't think this is what I need though. The copy/paste thing, I know how to do it. My question is: is it automatically feasible? Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: If you really want to do this using LaTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9164/file-copy-without-expansion