# Possible to Embed Base64 Encoded Images in TeX Documents?

Tags: graphics, xetex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding images with an encoding algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/embedding-images-with-an-encoding-algorithm)

Most of the examples I've seen explain how to insert images by using `graphicx` and external images. But I'd like to know if it's possible to Base64 encode the image, embed it into a TeX document, do whatever TeX layout/formatting with the image and have the image rendered out to PDF?

Comment: Please use the [search](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=base64) before open questions. This is an exact dup of [Embedding images with an encoding algorithm](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/embedding-images-with-an-encoding-algorithm).