# Directly embedded images

Tags: graphics, embedding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embedding images with an encoding algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/embedding-images-with-an-encoding-algorithm)

I'd like to embed an image (e.g. JPG, PNG) directly in my document.

In HTML it's possible with a base64-encoded src attribute.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgokIA..." />
```

Is this also possible in LaTeX?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for doing this? Your document would grow a lot and some editor might have problems to display your document...

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21541/embedding-images-with-an-encoding-algorithm