# Feed fontdimen parameters to TeX

Tags: fonts, tex-core, font-metrics

I have decided to [use `\fontdimen` parameters as an array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95635/2707) of numbers (to store data about Unicode Character Properties).  The question now is to fill in those `\fontdimen` parameters in the most efficient way.  I would much prefer methods that work for pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX.

The most efficient way is to load a `tfm` file `unicodedata.tfm` defining a font with many `\fontdimen` parameters.  The `tfm` file format begins with two bytes declaring its size in words (= 32 bits) as a signed integer (see `texdoc tftopl` or [an old TUGBoat paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-3/tb40fine.pdf)), so the maximum number of `\fontdimen` parameters declared through a `tfm` file is `32738` (slightly less than 2^15 because of some header information).  I need around 2^17.

*Maybe there exists a file format other than `tfm` to provide font metric to TeX?*

The other approach, much slower, is to do it inside TeX: something like

```
\font\foo=cmr10 at 1sp
\fontdimen 1\foo = 13459847sp
\fontdimen 2\foo = 14839847sp
% ...
\fontdimen 1114111\foo = 10872349sp
```

This is (presumably) slower because TeX has to parse each of these dimensions, and each entry takes around 10 characters in a file.  Space-wise, this can be improved and reduced to 4 bytes per entry, but that then requires even more work from TeX to decode.

Comment: Is there `\fontdimen0`? I don't think so. However, I think that the answer to your question is no. Split the information across eight TFM files to overcome the limitation.

Comment: I have to ask: what are you up to? :-)

Comment: @egreg -- correct, no `\fontdimen0`.  from appendix g, p.441: ",,, at least 22 `\fontdimen` parameters.  For brevity we shall call these parameters `\sigma_1` to `\sigma_{22}` ..."

Comment: The TeXbook, page 277: When a `\fontdimen` value is assigned, the `<number>` must be positive and not greater than the number of parameters in the font’s metric information file, unless that font information has just been loaded into TeX’s memory

Comment: @JosephWright Providing access to Unicode Character Properties in a cheap way, for use in regexps, for the collation algorithm, to get the correct choice of medial/final sigma when lowercasing, etc.  Basically, `\fontdimen <char-num>\unidatafont` gives a 25 bit integer (maximum providable through a tfm), where I can hopefully compress all Character Properties of that character.

Comment: You know that we have LuaTeX since 2007, which offers real data structures with Lua? :-)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Of course, but users are still using pdfTeX for good reasons (stability) and less good reasons (habit), or XeTeX for fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is something that you want loaded into memory every time someone compiles a document, then I think what you want to do is to load the font before dumping the format. As you know, the TFM limitation on the number of `\fontdimen` parameters is purely a file format limitation.

Here's my `special` format.

```
\font\unicodedata=cmtt6 at 1sp
\count0=0
\loop\ifnum\count0<"20000
    \advance\count0 by1
    \fontdimen\count0 \unicodedata=\count0 sp\relax
\repeat
\dump
\end
```

I can run¹ `pdftex -ini '&plain' special` and it'll dump a `special.fmt` with the `\unicodedata` font metrics loaded. The output will contain the line

```
\font\unicodedata=cmtt6 at 0.00002pt
```

Now, in `testspecial.tex`, I have

```
\def\X#1{%
    \message{^^JUnicode data #1=\number\fontdimen#1\unicodedata}%
}

\X{42}
\X{65536}
\X{"20000}
\end
```

Running `pdftex '&special' testspecial` produces²

```
(./testspecial.tex
Unicode data 42=42
Unicode data 65536=65536

Unicode data "20000=131072 )
```

---

¹ I'm not sure why running `pdftex -ini '&plain' special` fails to find `plain.fmt`. I'm pretty sure I've used this successfully in the past. *TeX by Topic* says to use `initex`, but that also fails to find `plain.fmt` and then tries `initex.fmt` which also fails.

² I'm also unsure what caused the extra line break in the output of `testspecial.tex`.

Comment: Thanks! I had no issues reproducing your answer and it's a good plan, although for now I might just use a bunch of separate TFM's.  About the linebreak: since plain has no new line char setup, `^^J` is just a normal char and `TeX` simply decides to break the line before your last `\message` because from its point of view the line is getting pretty long by then; of course the terminal displayed `^^J` as a line-break so the result looks odd.