# Undefining expl3 "intarray"s

Tags: expl3

As the manual of `l3intarray` says, for the command `\intarray_new:Nn`, variable assignments are always global, and that the size of the array is fixed and must be given at point of initialization.

This leads to a problem, for example my code defines

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  \intarray_new:Nn\g_myarray{#1}
  % Some useful operations with it here
}
```

then when I use `\mycommand` more than once it raises an error. However I can't put the initialization outside because the `{<size>}` is meant to vary. And I don't want to create a huge array to satisfy all cases.

By now, I have such a solution,

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
  \let\g_myarray\undefined
  \intarray_new:Nn\g_myarray{#1}
  % Some useful operations with it here
}
```

Is there any better way to do this, or is my method the only possible method?

Comment: No, create a huge array. Your method creates a "memory leak". (as usual, expl3 commands inherit limitations from the corresponding TeX primitive)

Comment: @user202729 Sorry, I couldn't understand the final part. Could you explain more?

Comment: Which part? For the memory leak part, every time you do `\let\g_myarray\undefined` you throw away the memory of the old array. For the primitive limitation part intarray is internally implemented using the method described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95635/using-fontdimen-as-an-array-to-store-data (see also texdoc source3) and there's no way to deallocate memory/"garbage collection" as explained there.

Comment: So my method is likely to take up too much memory? @user202729

Comment: `\int_array…` (ab)uses `\fontdimen` arrays. When you allocate one, a new font is loaded so it’s possible to assign it a number of `\fontdimen` parameters. When a font is loaded in TeX, it is stored in memory and it can’t be removed. Create a huge array.

Comment: If you don't know the array size, and it's dynamic, I'd usually stick to a 'classical' approach using a set of `int` values. Can you give details of the wider context?

Comment: @JosephWright I chose the intarray because it allows be to change the value of a certain term by providing its index and new value. This kind of operation happens a lot in my code.

Comment: @youthdoo Sure, but you can do that using an array of the form `\l__my_array_<n>_int`, i.e. a set of `int`s used to store one value each. For a dynamic array, that's likely a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `\intarray_new:Nn`, a font is loaded; it doesn't matter which one, because it's not used for typesetting but just in order to exploit a feature of TeX. From the TeXbook, pp. 277–278

> When a `\fontdimen` value is assigned, the `<number>` must be positive and
> not greater than the number of parameters in the font's metric information
> file, unless that font information has just been loaded into TeX's
> memory; in the latter case, you are allowed to increase the number of
> parameters (see Appendix F).

Then `\intarray_new:Nn` allocates as many `\fontdimen` parameters as specified in the second argument. It is not possible to change the number of parameters afterwards, as explained in the above quotation.

When a font is loaded, its metric information and its `\fontdimen` parameters are stored in memory and cannot be removed. There is a large amount of font memory nowadays; TeX Live 2022 sets

```
% Words of font info for TeX (total size of all TFM files, approximately).
% Must be >= 20000 and <= 147483647 (without tex.ch changes).
font_mem_size = 8000000

% Total number of fonts. Must be >= 50 and <= 9000 (without tex.ch changes).
font_max = 9000
```

While loading several `intarrays` should not be a big problem as regards to the number of fonts, it might be with respect to the font memory size. Let's see. With an empty LaTeX file, I get

```
 512287 words of font info for 32 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
```

If I add `\intarray_new:Nn \g_tmpa_intarray { 65536 }`, the figures become

```
 578116 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
```

The difference is 65829 and you see that allocating more than 8000000 parameters will require increasing `font_mem_size`. It's hard to imagine applications where such huge size of an array is needed.

Your strategy of undefining `\g_myarray` (by the way, this is inconsistent with the naming standards) will lead to memory fill up, sooner or later.

Allocate

```
\intarray_new:Nn \g_youthdoo_myarray_intarray { <number> }
```

with a big enough `<number>` of entries sufficient for your applications.

You may want to also allocate

```
\int_new:N \g_youthdoo_myarray_int
```

so when you set the values in `\g_youthdoo_myarray_intarray` you can also set the highest legal index in `\g_youthdoo_myarray_int` and when you retrieve a value you can check that its index is inside the currently set range.

Comment: From your ```\int_array_new:Nn```, are you talking about some array data structure under ```l3int```? Because I intended to ask about ```\intarray_new:Nn```. However in the rest of your post you didn't have the ```_```. Is it a typo? Or are these commands equivalent?

Comment: @youthdoo Sorry, typo.