# Write special characters to (aux) file

Tags: symbols, auxiliary-files, write-file

I would like to print a special character to an aux file. In particular, I would like to write the line

```
\@input{file.aux}
```

So far, I have achieved the best result with

```
\write\@auxout{\unexpanded{\@input{file.aux}}}
```

However, this approach produces an additional whitespace before the first bracket.

**What is the appropriate way to print special characters like `\` or `@` to an (aux) file?** The possibly related examples provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37753/write-macro-parameter-character-to-file) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8729/write-non-printable-ascii-characters-to-a-file) appear unnecessarily complicated and I am not quite able to implement them for my purpose.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please use full documents instead of fragments of code ;-)

Comment: The additional space is not of a concern, because it will be ignored at reading time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\string\@input{file.aux}` to write the stuff literally into the `.aux` file. As long no further expansion is involved, this is (the best?) way to get `TeX` commands literally into file output.

The `\immediate` is not really necessary, I just use it in almost any case, that's the only reason.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{%
  \string\@input{file.aux}%
}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I would like to confirm that it can also be used as ``\write\@auxout{\string\@input{file.aux}}``.